# jribbble not returning results

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dribbble-api

I have jribbble running on my page to bring back shots from my dribble page. It's been working for a while. However, the last few days has been showing this error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Site: http://atlantadesign.ninja/

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function getDribbbleShots() {   
  $.jribbble.getShotsByPlayerId('abenjamin765', function (playerShots) {
      var html = [];

      $.each(playerShots.shots, function (i, shot) {
          html.push(

            '<li class="tile"><div>'+
                '<a class="thumb" href="'+shot.image_url+'" data-lightbox="project" data-title="'+shot.title+'"><figure>⤢</figure>' +

                  '<img src="'+shot.image_url+'" alt="'+shot.title+'" />' +

                '</a>' +
                '<a class="link" href="'+shot.url+'">'+shot.title+' →</a>'+
            '</div></li>'
            );
      });
      $('.dribbble-feed').html(html.join(''));
      $('.dribbble-feed').append('<li class="tile"><div><a class="link special" href="http://dribbble.com/aBenjamin765" target="_blank">See more on Dribbble →</a></div></li>'); 
  }, {page: 1, per_page: 12});
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you read the full error you can see on the right hand side it tells you the URL which caused the error. In this case there's two 404s: `http://atlantadesign.ninja/favicon.ico` and `https://api.dribbble.com/players/abenjamin765/shots/?callback=jQuery1112028926326031796634_1445455731058&page=1&per_page=12&_=1445455731059`

Comment: right, but is this an error in the code or an error on dribbble's side?

Comment: I would guess their side, although It's possible you may be using an outdated version of their library which has outdated URLs.

Comment: Looks like you're right... I updated to the latest, but it looks like they removed the getShotsByPlayerID method. Not sure how to achieve the same thing with the new library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dribbble now requires you to register an application to get an API key.

Check out this example: http://codepen.io/tylergaw/pen/NqpzvE

```
// NOTE: Don't use this token, replace it with your own client access token.
$.jribbble.setToken('f688ac519289f19ce5cebc1383c15ad5c02bd58205cd83c86cbb0ce09170c1b4');

$.jribbble.users('tylergaw').shots({per_page: 36}).then(function(shots) {
  var html = [];

  shots.forEach(function(shot) {
    html.push('<li class="shots--shot">');
    html.push('<a href="' + shot.html_url + '" target="_blank">');
    html.push('<img src="' + shot.images.normal + '">');
    html.push('</a></li>');
  });

  $('.shots').html(html.join(''));
});
```